# Sum rows that have the same month in relation to the Date parameter

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-query-language

I'm using Google Sheets and I have two tables:

Table 1(Records): Columns [entry date, exit date and duration] > Duration is the difference between exit date and entry date. Only data from a single year are considered.

Table 2: 12 columns (one for each month). I need to make a row in the table display the sum of the durations for each respective month.

**Records:**

| Entry Date | Exit Date | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 02/01/2021 | 1 |
| 04/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 | 2 |
| 11/02/2021 | 15/02/2021 | 4 |
| 21/02/2021 | 24/02/2021 | 3 |
| 05/03/2021 | 06/03/2021 | 1 |

**Table2 must show:**

|  | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | ... | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| total duration | 3 | 7 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 |

What expression should I use to do this? Any answers/suggestions/tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(""&QUERY({TEXT(A2:A, "mm\×mmm"), C2:C; 
 IFERROR(TEXT(SEQUENCE(12, 1, 1, 28), {"mm\×mmm", "\0"*1}), 0)}, 
 "select sum(Col2) pivot Col1"), "^\d+×", ))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this solution also work with tables on different pages?

Comment: @Jhw_Trw yes, you just need to reference it properly (A2:A  > Sheet1!A2:A, etc.)